# How to compare two dates MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a report function, I store in my database some data with a specific value (closeDate), this value can be only 7th or 21nd, here is an example of my table:

[image: Table Example]

What I want to do is every 22nd execute a query to select all the register which have Status = "Active" or "On approve" and CloseDate < to 22nd (Curdate). I have this query, but this query show me all exactly like in the image and what I expect is that the query show me only the data from Id = 00001 and 00003 because Id 00002 CloseDate(2016-10-21) it's not < to 2016-09-22 (curdate).

```
SELECT tbl_usuarios.Correo, tbl_alertas.Id, tbl_alertas.Purpose, tbl_alertas.Status, tbl_alertas.OpenDate, tbl_alertas.CloseDate, tbl_alertas.Owner, tbl_alertas.ValueStream, tbl_alertas.Family
FROM tbl_usuarios 
INNER JOIN tbl_alertas ON tbl_usuarios.Nombre = tbl_alertas.Owner
WHERE STATUS = 'On approve' OR STATUS = 'Active' AND CloseDate < CURDATE()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to learn about [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html). Your query is executing as `status = 'approve' or (status = 'active' and closedat < curdate)` - note the brackets

Comment: To add to what Marc B said; it is generally seen as good practice to "force" precedence, even when it is not needed, to make the intent clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to rearrange your clauses in your WHERE condition.  It has both `OR` and `AND` so it may not be interpreted as you expect.

I would try something like this:

```
WHERE (STATUS = 'On approve' OR STATUS = 'Active') AND CloseDate < CURDATE()
```

Or you can simplify this using `IN`:

```
WHERE STATUS IN ('On approve', 'Active') AND CloseDate < CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that was something about () haha

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_usuarios.Correo, tbl_alertas.Id, tbl_alertas.Purpose, tbl_alertas.Status, tbl_alertas.OpenDate, tbl_alertas.CloseDate, tbl_alertas.Owner, tbl_alertas.ValueStream, tbl_alertas.Family
FROM tbl_usuarios 
INNER JOIN tbl_alertas ON tbl_usuarios.Nombre = tbl_alertas.Owner
WHERE (STATUS = 'On approve' OR STATUS = 'Active') AND DATE(CloseDate) < CURDATE()
```